# One-off Maori lesson in Auckland

Tags: new-zealand, study, languages, auckland

I'd like to attend a one-off Maori lesson in Auckland. I can find long-term courses and online courses, but I'm after something that's only for an hour or a couple of hours.

The lesson should include practicing pronouncing Maori while someone proficient in the language can hear me and give feedback.

Where are such lessons available?

Comment: So you want to learn to pronounce the text without understanding it/just repeat pre-written sentences?

Comment: Yes. Not because I don't want to learn grammar and vocab, but because I can work on that while I'm outside of NZ. I guess this is reminiscent of the role some foreigners have in the teaching of English in Japan.

Comment: I would go asking for that on an online forum or craigslist-like page, I would be quite surprised if that is offered in a regular manner by a school.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No luck it seems. I asked at a tourist info place in Auckland, and the staff member mentioned some places that offer long-term courses, but said that there isn't anything available on a one-off basis. He also suggested I try out relevant videos on YouTube.

Comment: I would try going to a Hangi (basically a Maori BBQ).  There a often ones that invite the public and you will find many people willing to share about their history and culture with you.  Here's a starting point http://www.inz.maori.nz/cuisine/traditional-hangi

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to other resources, I could recommend introductory flashcard apps like [Beginner Maori](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shex.beginnermaori) and [StartFromZero_Maori](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shex.startfromzero_maori) apps to start learning some basic Maori words and phrases on your own and at your own pace for free.